# Question on "smart" replacing in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I tell mathematica to do this replacement smartly? (or how do I get smarter at telling mathematica to do what i want)

```
expr = b + c d + ec + 2 a;
expr /. a + b :> 1

Out = 2 a + b + c d + ec
```

I expect the answer to be `a + cd + ec + 1`. And before someone suggests, I don't want to do `a :> 1 - b`, because for aesthetic purposes, I'd like to have both `a` and `b` in my equation as long as the `a+b = 1` simplification cannot be made.

---

In addition, how do I get it to replace all instances of `1-b`, `-b+1` or `-1+b`, `b-1` with `a` or `-a` respectively and vice versa?

Here's an example for this part:

```
expr = b + c (1 - a) + (-1 + b)(a - 1) + (1 -a -b) d + 2 a
```

Comment: `Replace` replaces subexpressions based on the structural equivalence (see `FullForm`), it doesn't perform any algebraic manipulations. You might try using `Reduce`, which is designed for these cases. I can't test it now though.

Comment: Might want to look into PolynomialReduce if the expression will generally be a polynomial.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a customised version of `FullSimplify` by supplying your own transformations to `FullSimplify` and let it figure out the details:

```
In[1]:= MySimplify[expr_,equivs_]:= FullSimplify[expr,
          TransformationFunctions ->
            Prepend[
              Function[x,x-#]&/@Flatten@Map[{#,-#}&,equivs/.Equal->Subtract],
              Automatic
            ]
        ]
In[2]:= MySimplify[2a+b+c*d+e*c, {a+b==1}]
Out[2]= a + c(d + e) + 1
```

`equivs/.Equal->Subtract` turns given equations into expressions equal to zero (e.g. `a+b==1` -> `a+b-1`). `Flatten@Map[{#,-#}&, ]` then constructs also negated versions and flattens them into a single list. `Function[x,x-#]& /@` turns the zero expressions into functions, which subtract the zero expressions (the `#`) from what is later given to them (`x`) by `FullSimplify`.

It may be necessary to specify your own `ComplexityFunction` for `FullSimplify`, too, if your idea of simple differs from `FullSimplify`'s default `ComplexityFunction` (which is roughly equivalent to `LeafCount`), e.g.:

```
MySimplify[expr_, equivs_] := FullSimplify[expr,
  TransformationFunctions ->
    Prepend[
      Function[x,x-#]&/@Flatten@Map[{#,-#}&,equivs/.Equal->Subtract],
      Automatic
    ],
  ComplexityFunction -> (
    1000 LeafCount[#] + 
    Composition[
      Total,Flatten,Map[ArrayDepth[#]#&,#]&,CoefficientArrays
    ][#] &
  )
]
```

In your example case, the default `ComplexityFunction` works fine, though.

Comment: wow thanks. It'll take me a little while before i fully understand that.

Comment: +1, for the construct `Function[x, x-#]&` alone. I was under the mistaken impression that wouldn't work, so it seems I need to re-evaluate some of my assumptions.

Comment: +1 for the Function and the clear explanation. Even with this, it took me a few minutes to fully grasp it.

Answer (score 5):

For the first case, you might consider:

```
expr = b + c d + ec + 2 a

PolynomialReduce[expr, {a + b - 1}, {b, a}][[2]]
```

---

For the second case, consider:

```
expr = b + c (1 - a) + (-1 + b) (a - 1) + (1 - a - b) d + 2 a;

PolynomialReduce[expr, {x + b - 1}][[2]]

(% /. x -> 1 - b) == expr // Simplify
```

and:

```
PolynomialReduce[expr, {a + b - 1}][[2]]

Simplify[% == expr /. a -> 1 - b]
```