# Simplifying a very long symbolic expression by automatically introducing temporal variables or in any other way

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, maple, symbolic-math

After attempting to solve a symbolic math problem, I got an expression with about 17000 characters. I am using the symbolic toolbox for Matlab, but I am open to any suggestion (Mathematica, whatever).

For obvious reasons, I won't copy-paste the expression straight into the question. [Here is a link instead](https://raw.github.com/gist/1702842/8aff11800e42140dd76265d288a1f4b4dc5ea995/gistfile1.txt).

Running the `Matlab` commands `simplify` and `simple`, and even attempts to `collect` didn't improve the situation (Some got it worse).

But I am wondering, I don't care if the expression is evaluated in steps, with temporal parameters. Something like:

```
 z1 = a^2*y1;
 %Now the expression can be simplified by using z1 as alias!
 z1+z1^2 ....
```

Is there an automatic method to get such a step-by-step simplification with temporal variables? Also, any other method that you can think of is plausible.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard Agreed. I nearly bought you one, until I looked at the price tag (they inflate everything...)

Comment: @Daniel I haven't decided if I should thank you or press charges. O_o

Comment: I can’t compare it directly with Matlab (I do not have this program), but it seems that Mathematica’s Simplify and FullSimplify are more efficient than similar commands in Matlab. After Simplify your expression has 2192 and after FullSimplify it has just 1535 characters. Perhaps this is enough simplification for you or it would be a good new starting point for further attempts of simplification.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! One main point of your question is about a simplification with temporal variables. I totally ignored this in my answer. So, in my opinion my comment stays just a comment and not an answer. But perhaps you can persuade me with some arguments ;-) Maybe your expression is after Mathematica’s simplification simple enough, then my comment would be in deed a (random-)answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might try common subexpression elimination (CSE). Here is an example cribbed from

[Get mathematica to simplify expression with another equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073530/get-mathematica-to-simplify-expression-with-another-equation)

```
InputForm[Experimental`OptimizeExpression[(3 + 3*a^2 + Sqrt[5 + 6*a + 5*a^2] +
      a*(4 + Sqrt[5 + 6*a + 5*a^2]))/6]]
```

==>

```
Out[206]//InputForm=
Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[{Compile`$1, Compile`$3, Compile`$4, 
   Compile`$5, Compile`$6}, Compile`$1 = a^2; Compile`$3 = 6*a; 
   Compile`$4 = 5*Compile`$1; Compile`$5 = 5 + Compile`$3 + Compile`$4; 
   Compile`$6 = Sqrt[Compile`$5]; (3 + 3*Compile`$1 + Compile`$6 + 
     a*(4 + Compile`$6))/6]]
```

Comment: Is there any way to set these variable `Compile**` as simple variable like c1,c3,c4,c5 etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in my comment, it seems that Mathematica’s simplification tools are more efficient than similar commands in Matlab.
Since it seems that you are a Matlab user, I give you here a detailed instruction how to use just two of the simplification commands of Mathematica.
If you define your long expression as

```
longExpression = (x3^2*(y2+y3-a*y1-a*y2-2*a*y3-...
```

Then you can use

```
Simplify[longExpression]  
and 
FullSimplify[longExpression]
```

The last produces a nice and clear expression which has just 1535 characters (sounds much, but there are not so many variables).
Perhaps this is enough simplification for your problem. If not, then let us know.

Comment: Could you please suggest me if there are any equivalent functions in Maple.